# UPI payment showing error "For security reasons, you are not allowed to send money from your bank account for this payment." in PhonePe

Tags: reactjs, ionic-framework, capacitor, google-pay, upi

UPI payment showing error "For security reasons, you are not allowed to send money from your bank account for this payment." in PhonePe and "You've exceeded the bank limit for thus payment" in Google Pay. There is no issue with bank limit on normal transactions.

Both the upi are normal account (none is a business account)

makeid() generate a random alphanumeric.

```
async function sendPayment(amt:String, pn:String, pa:String) {
const tid = makeid(15)
const tr = makeid(10)
var upiurl = 'upi://pay?pa='+pa+'&pn='+pn+'&tn=Brahma Electric Payment&tid=' + tid + '&tr=' + tr +'&am='+amt+'&cu=INR'
console.log(upiurl)
await window.open(upiurl)}
```

[image]

Can someone suggest where it is going wrong?

Comment: Hi, were you able to find any solutions to this error ?? I'm facing the same issue.

Comment: @user1368422 No, I did saw in some sources that the account we are paying to need to be a merchant account. I could test it though as I don't have it

Answer (score 1):

```
<EditText android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_marginRight="20dp" android:hint="Amount" android:inputType="number" />
```

Remove `android:inputType`